# Using react-hooks-testing-library with jest.spyOn - spy is not called

Tags: jestjs, react-hooks-testing-library

I am having an issue setting up a unit test to determine that a function is called with the correct arguments. `useAHook` returns function `foo` which calls function `bar`. The code looks like this

```
//myModule.js
export const useAHook = (arg1, arg2) => {
  const foo = useCallback(() => {
    bar(arg1, arg2);
  }, [arg1, arg2]);

  return foo;
}

export const bar = (a, b) => {
   //does some stuff with a and b
}
```

I am trying to unit test this code using `renderHook` and `jest.spyOn`. I want to confirm that calling function `foo` results in `bar` being called with the correct arguments. My unit test looks like this

```
//myModule.spec.js

import * as myModule from './myModule.js'

it('should call foo with correct arguments', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(myModule, 'bar');
  const { result } = renderHook(() => myModule.useAHook('blah', 1234));
  const useAHookFunc = result.current;

  useAHookFunc();

  // fails, spy is not called
  expect(spy).toBeCalledWith('blah', 1234);
});
```

The result is that the test fails saying that `spy` is never called. Am I doing something wrong here or using either tool incorrectly?

Comment: This indirectly solved an issue that I had for a while now. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line:

```js
import * as myModule from './myModule.js'
```

...imports the module bindings for `myModule.js` into `myModule`.

Then this line:

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn(myModule, 'bar');
```

...wraps the *module export* for `bar` in a spy...

...but the spy never gets called because `useAHook` doesn't call the *module export* for `bar`, it just calls `bar` directly.

---

If you modify `useAHook` to call the module export for `bar` then the spy will get called.

There are a couple of ways to do that.

You can move `bar` into its own module...

...or you can import the module bindings for `myModule.js` so you can call the module export for `bar`:

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';

import * as myModule from './myModule';  // <= import the module bindings

export const useAHook = (arg1, arg2) => {
  const foo = useCallback(() => {
    myModule.bar(arg1, arg2);  // <= call the module export for bar
  }, [arg1, arg2]);

  return foo;
}

export const bar = (a, b) => {
   //does some stuff with a and b
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to spy on the hook export method (using `import * as`), then inject a mock function into the implementation:

```
import * as useThingHook from 'useThing'

it('a test', () => {
  const methodMock = jest.fn()
  jest.spyOn(useThingHook, 'usething').mockImplementation(() => ({
    method: methodMock
  }))

  act()

  expect(methodMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

import * as myModule from './...'
const mockedFn = spyOn(myModule, "useSomething")